# How to use environment variables for secrets in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to configure Terraform so it uses environment variables for AWS Secrets.

terraform.tfvars:

```
access_key = "${var.TF_VAR_AWS_AK}"
secret_key = "${var.TF_VAR_AWS_SK}"
aws_region = "eu-north-1"
```

main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "${var.aws_region}"
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
}
```

In console(it's on Windows 10):

```
set TF_VAR_AWS_AK = asd12345asd12345
set TF_VAR_AWS_SK = asd12345asd12345
terraform plan
```

Error messages:

```
Error: Variables not allowed
  on terraform.tfvars line 1:
   1: access_key = "${var.TF_VAR_AWS_AK}"
Variables may not be used here.

Error: Variables not allowed
  on terraform.tfvars line 2:
  2: secret_key = "${var.TF_VAR_AWS_SK}"
Variables may not be used here.
```

Not sure where the problem is. TF docs say it is possible to use env vars for secrets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To configure *providers* and *backends* with environment variables, you don't need to write anything special in the configuration at all. Instead, you can just set the conventional environment variables related to the provider in question.

For example, you seem to be using AWS in which case you can use either the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`/`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables or you can populate a credentials file, the same as for the AWS SDK. You can then skip all of the declaration of variables and just reduce your provider block as follows:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.aws_region}"
}
```

Terraform's AWS provider supports the same set of credentials sources that the AWS CLI does without any Terraform-specific configuration. That is the recommended way to configure credentials for the AWS provider, because then you only need to set up your AWS credentials once and you can use both AWS SDK, Terraform, and any other software that interacts with AWS and supports its conventions.

There's more information on the AWS provider authentication options [in the AWS provider documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/2.42.0/docs#authentication).

Comment: Thank you, this is the right answer, just tried it and it all works with just `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`/`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. Your explanation cleared things up. I also thought all environment variables need to be prefixed with TF_VARS_ so they are picked up by TF.

Answer (score 1):

As described here in the documentation : https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#environment-variables

The environment variable names must be `TF_VAR_<yourtfvariablename>`.

With a terraform variable like this :

```
variable "aws_region" {
  type = string
}
```

Your environment variable name must be `TF_VARS_aws_region`

---

> There is actually no way to use environment variables directly in terraform. (ex: `region = env.AWS_REGION`) you **must** use `TF_VAR` to use env vars.